# Laravel - Date range search filter not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am trying to perform different search filters: username, email and date range. All other search filters are working except the date search.

Controller

```
public function revenueDetail(Request $request, $plan = null)
{
    $data['title'] = 'Revenue Detail Report';
    $revenuedetails = DB::table("users")
        ->select("users.username", "users.email",DB::raw("DATE(users.created_at) as subscription_date"))
        ->where('users.plan', self::$type[$plan] ?? null); // ?? will escape exception if $plan is null
        $render=[];
        if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
        {
            $revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
            $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
            $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
        }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
        {
            $revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->where('created_at',$request->start_date);
            $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        }        
        if(isset($request->username))
        {
            $revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->where('username','like','%'.$request->username.'%');
            $render['username']=$request->username;
        }
        if(isset($request->email))
        {
            $revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->where('email','like','%'.$request->email.'%');
            $render['email']=$request->email;
        }        
        $revenuedetails= $revenuedetails->orderBy('subscription_date','DESC');
        $revenuedetails= $revenuedetails->paginate(15);
        $revenuedetails= $revenuedetails->appends($render);
        $data['revenuedetails'] = $revenuedetails;
    return view('revenue.revenueDetail',$data);
}
```

View

```
    <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
        {{ Form::model(request(),['method'=>'get']) }}
        <div class="col-sm-2">
             {{ Form::text('username',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Username']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            {{ Form::text('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Email']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ Form::date('start_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ Form::date('end_date',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Date']) }}
        </div>        
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            {{ Form::submit('Search',['class'=>'btn btn-warning']) }}
            <a href="{{ route('gamesexport') }}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i> Excel</a>
        </div>
        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>


    <tbody>
        @foreach($revenuedetails as $key => $revenuedetail)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ ++$key }}</td>
                <td>{{ $revenuedetail->username }}</td>
                <td>{{ $revenuedetail->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $revenuedetail->subscription_date }}</td>
            </tr>

        @endforeach
            <tr>
            <td colspan="8">
                {{ $revenuedetails->links() }}
            </td>
            </tr>         
    </tbody>
```

When I click on the search button, I expect to see the result being displayed. All other search filters are working except the date search filter. It does not display any result.

1. How do I make it work
2. How do I format the date to dd/mm/yyyy

Thanks.

Comment: I can't see anything offhand that looks wrong but when I'm trying to get filters working, my usual strategy is to hand code the SQL I want first (which in your case is pretty straight-forward) then log the SQL statement that's produced and keep on working on it till I get it right:

    Log::info('User:' . Auth::user()->id . ' - ' . $query->toSql());

Comment: Idon't understand too. Its only the date filter

Comment: If you log $revenuedetails->toSql() you'll see the sql being produced and you'll know why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not getting the $request->start_date as `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, you may need to convert it to that format, and if you are only passing date, ie Y-m-d and want that to compare in your where query it should be

```
$start_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->start_date)->toDateTimeString()
$end_date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->end_date)->toDateTimeString()
$revenuedetails=$revenuedetails->whereBetween('created_at',[$start_date, $end_date]);
```

Comment: I did as you said but got this error:       "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2019-06-05T08:22:17+00:00Wed, 05 Jun 2019 08:22:17 +0000UTCam30UTC05_am30' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `users`.`plan` = 1 and `2019-06-05T08:22:17+00:00Wed, 05 Jun 2019 08:22:17 +0000UTCam30UTC05_am30` between 2019-05-27 and 2019-06-05) "

Comment: Use tablename.created_at instead of only created_at

Comment: The error is still there. after using users.created_at